# Get a result by comparing two tables with an identical column

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from on_connected;
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| id | extension | destination | call_id                   | created_at          |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| 11 |   1111111 | 01155555551 | 521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku | 2013-08-19 17:11:53 |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from on_disconnected;
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| id | extension | destination | call_id                   | created_at          |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |   1111111 | 01155555551 | 521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku | 2013-08-19 17:11:57 |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is a time difference of 4sec between the two. I would like to calculate the difference
using a query of some type. I'm aware of TIMEFIFF() and joins but lack the skills to form the query
at this point.

Here's my attempt thus far:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(to_seconds(od.created_at), to_seconds(oc.created_at)) 
FROM on_connected oc 
JOIN on_disconnected od 
ON oc.call_id=od.call_id 
WHERE call_id='521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku';
```

Mysql reports:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'call_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `JOIN` two tables using a column whose name is *identical* in both tables, you could use the `USING` clause instead of `ON`:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(to_seconds(od.created_at), to_seconds(oc.created_at)) 
FROM on_connected oc 
JOIN on_disconnected od 
USING(call_id)                             -- eq. to `od.call_id = oc.call_id`
WHERE call_id='521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku'; -- no need to specify the table name here
```

Non only this will save a few key stokes, but by doing so, you will be able to reference that column without specifying the table name.

Comment: Some excellent replies, fancyPants got in there first but I will be taking all answers into account for my db. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your where clause change

```
WHERE call_id='521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku';
```

to

```
WHERE oc.call_id='521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku';
```

or

```
WHERE od.call_id='521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku';
```

doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the differences for **all** times:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(od.created_at, oc.created_at)) 
FROM on_connected oc
JOIN on_disconnected od ON od.call_id = oc.call_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc655/1)

For a single `call_id`, you need to alias the column name in the filter:

```
WHERE oc.call_id = '521243ad953e-965inwuz1gku'
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc655/2)

Answer (score 1):

try oc.call_id in the where clause.

although the values will have matched at this point, the sql parser still needs to know which one you're referring to.